# MVC 3 Razor Как проверить аутентификацию при использовании jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Режим аутентификации - Forms, если это важно.
Есть функция Upload:

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Сохраняем файл на сарвер.
    }
}
```

Эфу функция вызывает jQuery скрипт (Uploadify):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#response').append("");
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Content/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
        'script': '@Url.Content("~/Functions/Upload")',
        'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Content/uploadify/cancel.png")',
        'folder': '/uploads/images',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': true,
        'fileDesc': 'изображения формата jpg, jpeg, png, tiff',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg'
    });
});
```

Вся проблема заключается в том, что при вызове функции Upload через аякс, `Request.IsAuthenticated=false`.
Как можно обойти эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

если вы работаете с ASP.NET MVC, используйте Action Filters, в вашем случае [Authorize]